# How to expand vector drawable?

Tags: android, xml

I was trying to expand my shape but only from one side.

What I have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx1EN.jpg

What I want to have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZUYw.jpg

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="368dp"
    android:height="257dp"
    android:viewportWidth="368"
    android:viewportHeight="257">
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,6H348C359.046,6 368,14.954 368,26V243H0V6Z"
      android:fillColor="#E7C9FF"/>
</vector>
```

How can I do this in Android Studio? Is there some kind of image scaling to achieve that? I don't want to change the resource code of this shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, its better yo use **9 patch** images. You wouldn't achieve this result any other way since changing width height ratio will make the image distorted.

You can specify the area which expands by giving it 1 pixel order, very easy to set up and there is a built in editor in Android Studio.

Make a PNG from your SVG first, then in Android Studio, right-click the PNG image you'd like to create a NinePatch image from, then click Create 9-patch file.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch

It takes literally a few seconds to create a 9 patch. You can also use [this online editor](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example) to build a nine patch without Android Studio.

(I was trying to make your drawable into a 9 patch but it had a white background which was causing issue.)
[image]

Comment: This is it what I was looking for! Thank you for response.